# How to hook write / read to Virtual hard disk

Tags: winapi

I want to create program like veracrypt (just to learn, I don't want to use it really, I just want to know how it's done).

Now , I know how to encrypt decrypt, how to create the vhd file (using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_vhd/) but, there is no API on about how to hook the read and write (as I don't want to store unencrypted data on the drive and then encrypt it, but encrypt / decrypt it on the go.

Is there anyway how to do that?

Comment: You can use file system filter drivers - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers

Comment: .vhd/.vhdx is just a file format. Asking how to hook reading/writing a .vhd/.vhdx file is like asking how to hook reading/writing a .txt file. I'm not sold on the idea that this question were meaningful or answerable.

Comment: "How to hook write / read to Virtual hard disk" it clearly states what is my idea :)

Comment: Sure, I understand your *idea*. I'm just not sure that the idea of hooking reading/writing a .pdf document is a meaningful concept. Data is just that: Data. It doesn't have behavior to it that you could intercept.

Comment: This is open source software. The "hook" is a driver: https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/tree/src/Driver

Comment: Thank you SimonMourier and nevilad :) you helped me a lot!